# Hadoop cluster for non-MapReduce algorithms in parallel

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

The Apache Hadoop is inspired by the Google MapReduce paper. The flow of MapReduce can be considered as two set of SIMDs (single instruction multiple data), one for Mappers, another for Reducers. Reducers, through predefined "key",  consume the output of Mappers. The essence of MapReduce framework (and Hadoop) is to automatically partition the data, determine the number of partitions and parallel jobs, and manage distributed resources.

I have a general algorithm (not necessarily MapReducable) to be run in parallel. I am not implementing the algorithm itself the MapReduce-way. Instead, the algorithm is just a single-machine python/java program. I want to run 64 copies of this program in parallel (assuming there is no concurrency issue in the program). i.e. I am more interested in the computing resources in the Hadoop cluster than the MapReduce frameworks. Is there anyway I can use the Hadoop cluster in this old fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Other way of thinking about MapReduce, is MR does the transformation and Reduce does some sort of aggregations.

Hadoop also allows for a Map only job. This way it should be possible to run 64 copies of the Map program run in parallel.

Hadoop has the concept of slots. By default there will be 2 map and 2 reduce slots per node/machine. So, for 64 processes in parallel, 32 nodes are required. If the nodes are of higher end configuration, then the number of M/R slots per node can also be bumped up.